# findAndModify an Object Using Variable Key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update a record which has a variable key and a pre-existing object associated with that key, as such:

```
[variable_name] : {
    date : 'XXXX'
}
```

How can I use findAndModify() to insert more key-values into that structure, without removing the existing data?  I could not figure it out using $set and an update object that resembled `updateObj[variable_name] = { newProp : newData }`.

Comment: try this db.collection.update({"variable_name.date":"XXXX"},{variable_name:{newProp : newData}})

Comment: Won't that use the string-literal "variable_name", where I want the data associated with the variable "variable_name"?

Comment: Yes but i assume your variable_name will not be change like initially your document like this --> {"key" : { "a" : 1 }} and after update it will be {"key" : { "b" : 2 }}

Comment: Sorry i missed last statement "insert more key-values into that structure" Hope this is you are looking db.collection.update({"variable_name.date":"XXXX"},{$set:{"variable_name.newProp":"newData"}},{"upsert":true})

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents)** operator together with the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)** to specify a new field in an embedded document. For example, since the `newProp` field does not exist and you specify a dotted path for that non-existent field, **[`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents)** will add the new field with the specified value thus creating the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the dotted path to the field. The `{upsert: true}` flag creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not insert a new document when no match is found:

```
db.collection.update(
   { "variable_name.date": ISODate("2015-09-23T18:06:00.696Z") },
   { $set: { "variable_name.newProp": "zzz" } },
   { "upsert": true }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Too late of an answer for the question but hope it helps others.

What you can do is the following, using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [Computed Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```
const key = `${variable_name}.newProp`;
db.update({_id: myId}, { $set: { [key]: newData } });
```